# Histogram of column counts and row counts with NA data

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I have data in the form:

```
Input_SNP   Set_1    Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6
1.09        0.162    NA        2.312     1.876     0.12      0.812
0.687       NA       0.987     1.32      1.11      1.04      NA
NA          1.890    0.923     1.43      0.900     2.02      2.7
2.801       0.642    0.791     0.812     NA        0.31      1.60
1.33        1.33     NA        1.22      0.23      0.18      1.77
2.91        1.00     1.651     NA        1.55      3.20      0.99
2.00        2.31     0.89      1.13      1.25      0.12      1.55
```

I would like to make a histogram plot of the total number of data in each column except for the Input_SNP column. For example, Set_1 has 6, Set_2 has 5, etc. I would also like to make a histogram plot of the total number of data in each except the top row obviously. How can this be done in R? This is a data frame.

Comment: I think you mean bar chart, not histogram. In other words, you want to compare values across several categories (columns or rows), not to visualize the distribution of a single variable, which is what a histogram does -- correct?

Comment: No, I want a histogram. I want to visualize the distribution of a single variable. I want 2 distributions. One distributions of column cells that aren't blank and one distribution of row cells that aren't blank. Does that make sense? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: So you're looking to make m + (n - 1) histograms of the values in each column and row except Input_SNP, not two bar charts comparing counts of non-NA values in each column and each row?

Comment: Or I see a third option, and maybe this is what you want: two histograms showing the distribution of counts of non-NA values across a) columns and b) rows?

Comment: The values that are being plotted are the number of data cells that are filled in a column. So if 3 of my columns have 6 cells filled and 1 cell empty. Then a histogram would should a bar at 6, that has a count of 3. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the counts of non-missing values in the columns (minus the first) and rows this way:

```
# Toy data to test
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(1, 1, NA, 3, NA), X2 = c(3, 4, NA, 1, 5), X3 = c(3, 4, 6, 1, 8))

# Now generate vectors of the counts
column.counts <- colSums(!is.na(df[,2:ncol(df)]))
row.counts <- rowSums(!is.na(df))
```

There are a few ways to make histograms. In base R, you could just call `hist(column.counts)` and `hist(row.counts)`. In `ggplot2`, you'd call `ggplot(NULL, aes(x=column.counts)) + geom_histogram()`. You can look at the help for those functions for details on how to fine-tune them.

Comment: Awesome! This is great! Do you know how I would delete a row if it's row.count is below a certain threshold. For example, say I have 100 columns, and a certain row only has data in 33 of those 100 columns. To keep a row I need data in at least 70 of the 100 columns. How would I delete that row with 33?

Comment: `df2 <- df[rowSums(!is.na(df)) >= x,]`, where `x` is your threshold value, like 70.